# Multiple line ListAdapter, using ListActivity

Tags: android, json, textview, listactivity, listadapter

I've run in to a problem with my Android application. What I'm trying to do is parsing data from a JSON API and then put the gathered data into a multiple line list using ListActivity. However, I cant seem to get it to work. I've tried Googeling for a solution but I cannot find anyone using the same method as me.

Anyone who can explain to me how I can get this to work?

**PubsActivity.java:**

```
public class PubsActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener, MyCallbackInterface{

private static String url = "http://api.fatkoll.se/json/1.0/getPlaces.json?api_key=fd6950b1499b71037ec3c5a5e01081d6&city_id=";


static String TAG_LIST = "list";
static String TAG_ID = "id";
static String TAG_NAME = "name";
static String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
static String TAG_OPEN_HOURS = "openhours";
static String TAG_LAT = "lat";
static String TAG_LNG = "lng";

private static String address;
private static String openhours;
private static String lat;
private static String lng;

private ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] toId = new int[] {R.id.listName ,R.id.listAddress};
private ArrayList<String> pubIds = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray list = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pubs);

    Intent getCityId = getIntent();
    String cityId = getCityId.getExtras().getString("cityId");

    JSONparser parser = new JSONparser(this);       
    parser.execute(url);

}



@Override
public void onRequestComplete(JSONObject result) {

    JSONObject json = result;

    try {

        list = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LIST);
        Log.e("onRequestComplete", "Fått JSONArray");


        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e("onRequestComplete", list.getString(i));
            pubIds.add(c.getString(TAG_ID));
            info.add(c.getString(TAG_NAME));
            info.add(c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
            openhours = c.getString(TAG_OPEN_HOURS);
            lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
            lng = c.getString(TAG_LNG);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
    Log.e("onRequestComplete", "Skapar ArrayAdapter");
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.e("onRequestComplete", "Sätter ListAdapter");
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

**JSONparser.java:**

```
package se.mima.jeda.frsa.krogrunda;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONparser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

// Initializing variables

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public interface MyCallbackInterface {
    public void onRequestComplete(JSONObject result);
}

private MyCallbackInterface mCallback;

public JSONparser(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Make a HTTP request
    try {
        // Creating a DefaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // skapar en HttpPost
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        // Catching exceptions
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // BufferedReader reads the data gathered from the API
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Trying to parse a JSONObject from a String
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return JSONObject
    return jObj;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    return getJSONFromUrl(url);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    mCallback.onRequestComplete(result);
}

}
```

Comment: Where is exactly the problem?

Comment: I believe its here:

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
    Log.e("onRequestComplete", "Skapar ArrayAdapter");
    setListAdapter(adapter);

I somehow need to make a adapter that accepts two lists, one that holds the data and one that tells the adapter wich data goes to wich line. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your own BaseAdapter (see Google examples [List 14](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) here) for your data. Currently you are showing "Name" and "Address" of each list entry alternating in the list, because you are storing this data into one ArrayList. Using BaseAdapter you can put your own custom data objects into the list adapter and are free how to present it in the list.